# send email to multiple email address rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am a user model and in my view I have:

```
@user = current_user
```

User model have an attribute with name "**email**".

and I want send one e-mail to multiple email address with a subject.

I have a form like:

```
<%= form_for (Email.new), :method => :post, :remote => true, :url => { :controller => "users", :action => "invite_friends" } do |f|  %>     
<%= f.text_field :address1 %>
<%= f.text_field :address2 %>
<%= f.text_field :address3 %>
<%= f.text_field :address4 %>
<%= f.text_area :subject_email %>                   
<% end %>
```

Have I that create a **"email model"** with attributes **address** and **subject_email**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check section 2.3.3 [Sending Email To Multiple Recipients](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-email-to-multiple-recipients) from the Rails Guide

Comment: Thank you but I want to know that fields that I send from form In my model user I have not fields `:address` or `:subject_email`... have I create this fields in my model? Thank you!

Comment: no you do not need those fields in your model - you supply :from and :to and :subject them as arguments to the mail() command, they might come from your database, or they might be hard-coded such as :from => appname@example.com, :to => admin@example.com, :subject => "internal application error alert #1234"